# AnyLogic - determination of lane in road traffic

Tags: anylogic

In my model, car-agents sort in the correct lanes just a few car-length before the crossing when the traffic light is green. That way, the intersection gets unrealistically inefficient. What I can not find in the APIs is a way to **determine the lane choice x meter before the intersection**.

> Is there a parameter, if not any idea, to set the lane choice of car-agents in front of a crossing?

Thankful for any thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found intermediate stop lines, which only cover certain lanes, can be used to give you more precise control.  You can send a car to the intermediate stop line, and then send on to the final destination of choice.

Comment: Thank you, Amy. Valuable hint! Unfortunately, it does not apply to my specific intersection where I probably need to accept the randomness, as mentioned by Felipe. Thanks again, to both of you! Best

Answer (score 0):

the lane can only be chosen in the beginning when the car is created or through the enter/exit blocks... otherwise you have to just accept the randomness of the internal model and you have no control over it.

Edit: but amy in her answer is right that you can redirect cars to strategic intermediary stop lines in order to choose the lane or group of lanes the cars will choose whenever it's going to a certain destination.